# get bootstrap multiselect selected values

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I know its simple solution,sorry for asking,but cant figure out it myself.

```
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="sort"><?php _e('Sort', 'bootstrapwp'); ?><span class="help-required">*</span></label>
          <select name="sort" id="sort" class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow form-control required sort" multiple title="Vali sort..."role="select" aria-required="true" multiple data-max-options="10">
          <optgroup label="Varajased">
          <option>Honeoye</option>
          <option>Rumba</option>
          <option>Lambada</option>
          <option>Darselect</option>
          </optgroup>
          </select>               
        </div>
```

my multiselect form looks like above,and i want to get selected values from there displayed after last single value,which is $suhtluskeel\n\n:

```
$body = "Eesnimi: $eesnimi\n\n Perekonnanimi: $perekonnanimi\n\n E-mail: $email\n\n Kontakttelefon: $phone\n\n Aadress: $aadress\n\n Suhtluskeel: $suhtluskeel\n\n";
```

how can i add this code i found

```
$('#multiselect1').multiselect({
...
onChange: function() {
    console.log($('#multiselect1').val());
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap your multi-select code inside `$(document).ready` function -

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#multiselect1').multiselect({
        onChange: function() {
          console.log($('#multiselect1').val());
        }
      });
   });
```

Also there is an alternative if you face any problem with your code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#multiselect1').multiselect({
        onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
            console.log('Changed option ' + $(option).val() + '.');
        }
    });
});
```